# Отпимизация алгоритма обхода дерева

Tags: javascript, кодировка

Нужно оптимизировать данный код, чтоб результат выполнения программы получить быстрее чем через пару миллионов лет. Все на первый взгляд просто, но я уже замылил глаза окончательно. Буду благодарен любой подсказке.

```
function buildRandomTreeFromCenterRightLeft(s) {
  if (s == '') {
    return null;
  }
  var center = s.substr(0, 1);
  var rightAndLeft = s.substr(1);
  var rightLength = Math.floor((rightAndLeft.length + 1));
  var right = rightAndLeft.substr(0, rightLength);
  var left = rightAndLeft.substr(rightLength, rightAndLeft.length);
  return {
    center: center,
    left: buildRandomTreeFromCenterRightLeft(left),
    right: buildRandomTreeFromCenterRightLeft(right),
  };
}

function printTreeLeftCenterRight(tree) {
  if (tree == null) {
    return '';
  }
  return printTreeLeftCenterRight(tree.left) + tree.center + printTreeLeftCenterRight(tree.right);
}

function printTreeRightLeftCenter(tree) {
  if (tree == null) {
    return '';
  }
  return printTreeRightLeftCenter(tree.right) + printTreeRightLeftCenter(tree.left) + tree.center;
}

function findEmail(centerRightLeft, leftCenterRight) {
  while (true) {
    var tree = buildRandomTreeFromCenterRightLeft(centerRightLeft);
    if (printTreeLeftCenterRight(tree) == leftCenterRight) {
      var email = printTreeRightLeftCenter(tree);
      console.log(email);
      break;
    }
  }
}

var easyProblem = {
  centerRightLeft: 'damEra@ilh',
  leftCenterRight: 'hal@irdamE',
}
findEmail(easyProblem.centerRightLeft, easyProblem.leftCenterRight);
var hardProblem = {
  centerRightLeft: '.o elPsaec lamei.a sur@h treotrdil0ems.al Pe7  dnse8dco9e:i438f7bfc5224b5d151bdc4ai bc91eamuoy ne r',
  leftCenterRight: 'er muyn oaia1e 9cbi14bdcc55d15b4227fb43f8l:9e8odc7dens  0eaPl s.em.iderotrr@t h.aus c ilaemo saeelP',
}
findEmail(hardProblem.centerRightLeft, hardProblem.leftCenterRight);
```

по условию `easyProblem` код отрабатывает 600-10000 итераций и выдает результат. На `hardProblem` виснет надолго. Пробовал построить дерево на основе второго поля ключа (с которым происходит сравнение), но безуспешно. Пробовал кучу разных вариаций построения, но с отправной точки не сдвинулся. Кажется мне все проще и опытный глаз сразу найдет способ.

Comment: Пока что я вижу, что ваш код делает одно и то же в бесконечном цикле. В функции нет ничего случайного несмотря на random в названии

Comment: спасибо, но тем не менее, у вас есть идеи как оптимизировать код чтоб получить искомый вывод до того как сгорит солнце?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут не нужен случайный перебор. Нужно просто последовательно решить задачу. Например из условия:

```
var easyProblem = {
  centerRightLeft: 'damEra@ilh',
  leftCenterRight: 'hal@irdamE',
}
```

видно, что вершина дерева это буква `d`. Найдём её в `leftCenterRight`. Всё, что идёт до этой буквы это левое поддерево, что после — правое. Итого задача сводится к:

```
var easyProblem = {
  centerRightLeft: 'damEra@ilh',
  leftCenterRight: 'hal@irdamE',
  center: 'd',
  leftTree: {
    centerRightLeft: 'ra@ilh',
    leftCenterRight: 'hal@id'
  },
  rightTree: {
    centerRightLeft: 'amE',
    leftCenterRight: 'amE'
  }
}
```

Далее решаем задачу рекурсивно (как у вас уже написано).

Важно помнить, что:

1. Символ может встречаться в строке несколько раз и нужно выбрать правильное разбиение;
2. Формально подходящих решений может быть несколько, но не все будут давать осмысленную фразу.